# 10x4 Table of random intergers not printing, prints zeros C

Tags: c

i am attempting to print a 10x4 table of random intergers. i compiled the code and get no errors but the compiled code prints the table full of zeros. Can anyone help figure out why?

```
int main(void)
{
    int row = 0, column = 0 ;
    while (column < 11)
    {
         row = 1;
         while (row < 5)
         {
             printf ("%lf", random());
            row = row + 1;
         }
     column = column + 1;
     }

}
```

Comment: Please show the code for `random()`

Comment: random is a function that produces randomn intergers. or it should anyway

Comment: What is this `random` function is? I encountered it [twice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21356545/2455888) today.

Comment: Missing `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: ... Well there is hope for the person - managed to indent the code

Comment: It should be noted that you've got your columns and rows backwards, and you probably should output a `"\n"` at the end of each row.  Also, the above code will print 11 "columns" instead of 10.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you are using the [`POSIX`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/random.html) `random` function:

```
long int random(void);
^^^^^^^^
```

In C the function `printf` isn't typesafe. So the long integer returned by `random` will be interpreted as a `double` by `printf`, which is unlikely to produce anything meaningful. You might want to print a `%ld`.

While you are at it you might also want to call `srandom` or a seed of 1 will always be used.

Comment: Where is this `random` and `srandom` functions are in library ?

Comment: @haccks Fair enough, I assumed the OP is using the POSIX `random`.

Comment: sorry, i forgo to include that in my code, but yes i am using that and your suggestion fixed it

Comment: OK. Fine. I thought it is C standard library function :)

Comment: haccks: try "man random" : 
NAME
       random, srandom, initstate, setstate - random number generator

SYNOPSIS
       #include <stdlib.h>  . So it's in "stdlib.h"

Comment: @IngoBlackman; Tried to compile the code with including `<stdlib.h>` but did't compiled.

Comment: @haccks What platform are you on ?

Comment: @haccks: which compiler (Visual C++ ?), what error do you get ?

Comment: @haccks Hm, chances are the library you're using doesn't conform to POSIX (i.e. if you are using vs cpp you won't have `random`).

Comment: @hacks: another possiblity: The code above is missing the "return"  at the end of main. If your compiler is picky it at least will complain about that...

Comment: @cnicutar; I am using GCC.

Comment: @IngoBlackman; I compile codes in C99 mode. You can omit `return 0` from `main` in C99 mode.

Comment: Note: Per C11 and [rand(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand), `int rand(void)`, so recommend `printf ("%d", random());`, not `"%ld"`.

Comment: @chux That's for `rand`, `random` returns a `long int`.

Comment: @cnicutar Right you are.